# Get all git projects members (gforge)

Tags: git, gitlab, gforge

I am in process of migrating projects from gforge to gitlab. I need to get the list of all project members with their email.

I already used the command `git shortlog -se` and it worked for most of the projects but I have few ones where not all the members has done commits and I am not able to get their mails neither by command nor by the graphical interface of the platform(gforge).

I need a command that lists all projects members and their **login emails** without passing by the `log` or `shortlog` and regardless of their previous actions on the project.

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with SQL, you might try using psql and writing a query against the GForge database, instead of using the git metadata, which can be less consistent.

Before you do that, of course, I'd invite you to check out [GForge Next](https://gforge.com/products) and see if those features match your needs.  There's a direct upgrade path from GForge AS, it's Docker-based, and you won't have to migrate any data.